# Lenskit: How to run LensKit recommender and evaluator from java

Tags: java, lenskit

I have a maven project in which I have a java file that pre-processes the data and creates a number of new data files that would like to be the input files in the `Lenskit`. When the evaluator finishes the evaluation of each file, I would like to get the result values (`RMSE` etc) back in my java code to continue with my kind of analysis. So, I guess that somehow I need to call the evaluator process each time a new data input file is generated and take the `RMSE` and other metrics values as output. Does anybody know how could I possibly do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [SimpleEvaluator](http://lenskit.grouplens.org/maven-site/apidocs/org/grouplens/lenskit/eval/traintest/SimpleEvaluator.html) exists for that very purpose.